# asp.net mvc - [HttpPost/HttpGet] vs. [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post/Get)]

Tags: asp.net-mvc

are these things the same?

```
[HttpPost/HttpGet] vs. [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post/Get)]
```

if not where is a difference?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, absolutely the same. `[HttpPost/HttpGet]` were introduced in ASP.NET MVC 2 to reduce the keystrokes we have to type :-) `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post/Get)]` could still be used and behave the same although if you are writing new code I would recommend the first.

Answer (score 24):

Yes they are the same but with the newer versions you can only make an action accept requests from one verb. Using `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Delete)]` you can accept 2 or more. Also you can use `[AcceptVerbs]` to accept other verbs that are not part of the `HttpVerbs` enum - eg. `[AcceptVerbs("Trace")]`.

I'm not sure why you would ever need to use this functionality but you are able to should you wish.

Comment: I'm dealing with one reason myself -- I've just discovered an Update endpoint that only accepts the POST verb. In order to switch it to PUT, I have to accept both verbs for a few builds until all the clients are updated.

Comment: +1 for *you can use `[AcceptVerbs]` to accept other verbs that are not part of the HttpVerbs enum - eg. `[AcceptVerbs("Trace")]`*