# Use Get And Post in the same Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I want to use the HttpGet and HttpPost attributes for one action method. However, I have only seen examples where the attributes are used individually on separate action methods.

For example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Code...
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {
        //Code...
        return View();
    }
```

I want to have something like this:

```
[HttpGet][HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
{
    //Code...
    return View();
}
```

I remember having seen this done somewhere, but cannot remember where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do that, you can use the `[AcceptVerbs]` attribute. (See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744990/asp-net-mvc-httppost-httpget-vs-acceptverbshttpverbs-post-get))

This way your method can handle the GET and POST verbs (but not others like PUT)

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
{
    //Code...
    return View();
}
```

If you want your method to handle all verbs, don´t use any attribute at all:

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
{
    //Code...
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is that i want (y)